# View the published Developer Portal without private browsing mode in Azure API Management

Tags: azure, azure-api-management, azure-api-apps, ibm-api-management

When accessing the new developer portal in Azure API Management in the same browser session in which being connected to Azure, the administrative version of the portal is opening.

However, developers of my team use to develop API, but also to consume it. So it would be preferable to view the portal directly in published mode (like the old developer portal) rather than opening a new private browsing window, and logging into Azure (that is a long process in my company, because of MFA).

Is there maybe a trick to bypass this too long process and to access directly the developer portal in published mode?

Thank you very much for your help!

Best regards,

Grégoire

Comment: If you encounter the same need, you can upvote this request on the Azure APIM User Voice : https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management/suggestions/41136253-developer-portal-view-the-published-portal-witho

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The new Develop Portal has been in progress, and **your needs are temporarily not supported**, so **it cannot be resolved at this time**.

You can put forward your needs in [azure apim user voice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/248703-api-management), so that the development team can better improve the product.